# Contact Layout Editor menu item not available

Tags: extension, contact-layout-editor

I installed the new Contact Layout Editor extension, but I am not finding the new menu item, which should be at Administer / Customize Data and Screens.

Joomla 3.8.12
Civi 5.5.1

(Aside: in this process, I discovered that the extension created a new SQL table as MyISAM, which threw a warning in Civi. Easy enough to change the table to InnoDB, but it seems like a new extension should be using InnoDB by default. See https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout/issues/14. Fixing the engine did not solve the problem of the missing menu.)

Comment: Same here, but using Drupal - except the table was created as InnoDB.  But no menu item.  Bootstrap theme installed in Drupal, met all the prereqs but no menu item.  Frustrating!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem but fixed it - the problem was that I didn't have the pre requisites installed *before* installing the extension. One of them I installed afterwards. So, I disabled then uninstalled the contact layout extension, then re-installed it.  Then the menu item appeared as 'Contact Summary Layouts' as the last item on the 'Customise Data and Screens' menu.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried disabling/re-enabling the extension, but I didn't uninstall it. The full uninstall did the trick.

Comment: ditto same problem. full ininstall/resinstall fixed it